# Google Play: Upload new APK failed. APK is signed with different certificate to previous APK.

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-keystore

```
Upload failed

You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different certificate to your previous APKs.
You must use the same certificate.

Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 33:00:07:BA:2B:DC:9C:29:B0:B9:54:F1:AA:C9:9C:00:6A:D0:93:35 ]

and the certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
[ SHA1: 60:BB:1D:CA:5F:5A:0B:7C:62:8B:11:CE:88:2D:FC:8F:FA:ED:D6:FD ]
```

I am using same Key Store to generate signed APK. Previously I generated signed APK from Windows OS but this time from a Linux Ubuntu using SAME key store.

Comment: Are you use Android studio in both Window and Linux ? Please make sure you use same "Release certificate" (NOT Debug certificate) in both Window and Linux.

Comment: I'm using Android Studio in both Windows and Linux.

Comment: I have signed my application in release mode both from windows and now from Linux also.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use the same **File** and not just create the "same" certificate by using same login / password / infos to generate it.

Are you sure to use **Release** key and not **debug** ?

Comment: Yes. I'm using Release Mode and not Debug Mode, as suggested here [link] (http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Comment: Can you elaborate. Your answer is a bit obscure.

Answer (score 0):

Open your gradle and double check again your keystore key

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate. Since gradle scripts has many files, how can I open this gradle file.

Comment: This file is build.gradle (Module:app) and check the signingConfigs

Comment: For some reasons my build.gradle (Module:app) file does not have signingConfigs property. This is what mine looks like:

Comment: apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.iotaconcepts.app_ologize"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 2
        versionName "2.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
}

Comment: You can check my build.gradle (Module:app) file at : https://github.com/prasang7/ReleaseError_Build.GradleFile

Comment: Hmm, you can open File - > Project Structure. In the left side, in Modules , select app. In the Right side, select tab "Signing" and add your certificate here. Then, in Build Types tab, choose "Release" and select your key in Signing Config option. Save and re-build and generate signed apk file again.

Comment: Did everything, step by step. No improvement. Still same error pops up every time I upload the APK on store.

Comment: Are you try install apk file from Window build. Then, set certificate for Debug mode in Linux. Run project in device already installed app. Check error status.